# What does 'Apply yourself' really mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms

For a long long time, I thought that applying oneself meant that whatever I know, I should be able to apply that to a problem that is presented to me. For example, if I was asked something, and I didnt know the solution completely, but knew the basics of the problem, then I should be able to think out a reasonable solution and present it forward.

I thought applying oneself was mostly around 'you understand the basics of this topic, I can solve the problems around this topic even though I do not know this. I can apply myself.'

But I googled and the answer that I got for 'Applying Oneself' was that to work hard.

So what is it then? Also, what is the phrase that I can use in the following scenario.

I am a new member to the team of 5 who are working on a business problem. Even though, I do not understand the problem, I understand the logical reasoning behind what the speaker is trying to present. So I am able to follow and even ask/make suggestions. In this case, I do not know the problem inside out, but the fact that it is a logical reasoning sort of thing, and I have been good at that sort of stuff, so will I say that I was 'applying myself'? or something else?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds more like personal or work advice rather than what the words in English mean. For more likely helpful results to your situation, try workplace.SE

Comment: @Mitch Actually, I used that scenario for no particular reason. I could very well have taken an example, where a teacher is telling the students to apply themselves when a new problem is given.

Comment: In general it means "work".  (Listen closely and you will hear an echo from Maynard.)

Comment: As defined at [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/apply+oneself)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Apply yourself" means to put in the effort required to master a subject or attain some other goal.  Here's a good example of the usage from [*A Cab Called Reliable: A Novel*](https://books.google.com/books?id=yFVWVaT_Kh4C&pg=PA98&dq=%22apply%20yourself%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBjgKahUKEwjo8f-1pLPHAhVEWD4KHdmzAE0#v=onepage&q=%22apply%20yourself%22&f=false) by Patti Kim:

> From her leather-upholstered, swiveling recliner, she leaned down at
>   me and said, "If you want to succeed here and in your life, you must
>   focus, concentrate, and **apply yourself**.

Answer (score 4):

It's say it's much more about exertion than about skill. I think it holds a connotation of perseverance or laboring for an extended period.

"Put your back into it" is similar.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your **second question**, here are phrases for the **scenario** you gave where you work your way into a subject without seeing the whole picture.

Participation, or hands-on experience allows you to understand the practicalities, and allows you "get to grips with the problem,"  "get your hands dirty," or "[know the business from the bottom up](http://dioms.thefreedictionary.com/learn+from+the+bottom+up)," or simply "[get stuck in](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+stuck+in)."

On the other hand, theoretical knowledge, "understanding the *rationale,"* and "the whys and wherefores" give theoretical understanding of the situation.

*Notes:*
[get stuck in (the Free Dictionary) 
To begin doing something at once and with energy and/or enthusiasm.]
[get your hands dirty. (informal).[Idioms by The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+hands+dirty%20Get%20hands%20dirty%20-) to involve yourself in all parts of a job, including the parts that are unpleasant, or involve hard, practical work Unlike other bosses,]

Answer (score 0):

For the first question:

*Apply yourself* means *Work hard, make a serious effort.*

For the second question:

You were **applying your skills** [to the new problem].